# Change GTK theme from command line

Tags: command-line, gtk, theme

I was able to change my GTK theme with `lxappearance` but would prefer to know the command (or multiple commands, if GTK2 and GTK3 themes need to be set separately).

At the moment, I'm on an Ubuntu derivative with i3wm but I was curious whether there is a general command/answer--other answers on the Internet appear outdated. I had tried setting `org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme` but I imagine that only works in GNOME environments (not i3wm).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and change the line that begins with `gtk-theme-name`

Answer (score 0):

To run any gnome/gtk3,4 application from the command line while setting the gtk theme to any theme installed in `/usr/share/themes` (or the user directory, e.g. generally `$HOME/.local/share/themes`) you can simply use the `GTK_THEME="...your theme name..."` environment variable,

e.g. to run `gnome-sudoku` with the `Material-Black-Blueberry` theme, you would do:

```bash
$ GTK_THEME="Material-Black-Blueberry" gnome-sudoku
```

Using the `GTK_THEME` environment variable allows you to test a number of different themes much more quickly than editing `/etc/gtk-3.0/setting.ini` (and/or `/etc/gtk-4.0/setting.ini`) every time.