# Recovering from a 'corrupt' theme installation on Debian

Tags: debian, gnome, login, theme

I recently installed a new theme on my Debian Stretch machine, however after rebooting, I am unable to get past the login screen. If I enter the incorrect log in details, the systems tells me that the wrong credentials were provided, however if I enter the correct details, nothing happens for a few seconds, then the screen flashes black then goes back to the login screen.

Theme in question: [Flat Remix Gnome](https://github.com/daniruiz/flat-remix-gnome)

I followed the `terminal installation` instructions, and everything seemed to be fine until after a reboot.

I can still login view terminal (switching to a terminal session when I hit the login screen), however I do not know how I can remove this theme and get back to the default one, which will hopefully allow me to log in via the gnome login screen.

Any suggestions?

I've looked at [how to change theme from terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323060/change-gtk-theme-from-command-line?newreg=a63842777a7a4115803117dd24c07a2b) however my `settings.ini` file only very little information in it, and does not contain what the answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try uninstalling the theme? `--purge` will remove config files too (source: `man apt-get`). After uninstalling remove ppa:daniruiz/flat-remix.

```
 $ sudo apt-get remove --purge flat-remix-gnome
 $ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:daniruiz/flat-remix
```

Also that webpage talks about installing from terminal and shows some paths where you could find theme files and delete them by hand:

```
 $ sudo mv /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource.old &&
 $ sudo ln /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell-theme.gresource /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

ln made a "shortcut" to the files, you can remove that and system probably wont know where to find files even if they are on the filesystem, therefore not use them. Files you are searching for are (at least according to terminal installation paths) located at: `/usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/`. Remove the whole folder. (or the symbolic link "shortcut" that points to that). You could also rewrite that link to point at another theme, similarly to the ln command mentioned here, but put another theme in first path.